# Hortonworks Sandbox Error Connecting to Tableau

Tags: hadoop, odbc, tableau-api, hortonworks-data-platform

I am using the HortonWorks Sandbox and trying to connect to tableau but get the following error. I am able to select my table and columns in tableau but cannot access the values. This is after granting admin privileges to my user in hive.

Error:

> [Hortonworks][HiveODBC] (35) Error from Hive: error code: '40000' error message: 'Error while compiling statement: FAILED: HiveAccessControlException Permission denied. Principal [name=hue, type=USER] does not have following privileges on Object [type=TABLE_OR_VIEW, name=bse_stock_test.bse_index] : [SELECT]'.
>
> Unexpected Error

Comment: So the user "hue" is able to execute a select query on the bse_stock_test table/view in Hortonworks?

Answer (score 2):

user: hue should have permission to access the table.

In your case user: `hue` should have permission to access `bse_stock_test.bse_index`.

Try below command. It worked for me.

```
GRANT SELECT on table <table_name> to user <user_name>;
```

Ex:

```
grant SELECT on table batting to user hue
```

Comment: It worked! However, I found strange the need to give GRANT permission to the user that created the table (hue).

Answer (score 0):

If you're connecting to Hive, make sure that user has write permissions to the **/tmp/hive-hive folder**. We had the a similar issue and that is what resolved the ODBC driver issue in both Tableau and Excel.